# How to get correct summaries with analytics?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, window-functions

I want to get summary numbers from the `cust_detail` table if a specific `invoice_code` appears in `invoice_detail`.

In this example, I'd like to report cust_detail summaries only for batches `10` and `20` because they are the ones with `invoice_code='9999'`. But the duplication in the `invoice_detail` table is skewing my numbers.

```
with
  invoice_detail as
  (
    select '10' as invoice_batch, '9999' as invoice_code from dual union all 
    select '10' as invoice_batch, '9999' as invoice_code from dual union all
    select '20' as invoice_batch, '1111' as invoice_code from dual union all
    select '30' as invoice_batch, '9999' as invoice_code from dual
  ),
  cust_detail as
  (
    select '1' as cust_id, '10' as invoice_batch, 40 as points_paid, 30 as points_earned, 30 as points_delivered from dual union all
    select '1' as cust_id, '20' as invoice_batch, 10 as points_paid, 10 as points_earned, 10 as points_delivered from dual union all
    select '1' as cust_id, '30' as invoice_batch, 20 as points_paid, 15 as points_earned,  5 as points_delivered from dual
  )
select cust_id, 
       sum(points_paid) over (partition by  c.invoice_batch
                                  order by cust_id) batch_total
  from cust_detail c
 inner join invoice_detail i on c.invoice_batch=i.invoice_batch
 where i.invoice_code = '9999';
```

Desired results:

```
 CUST_ID   PAID   EARNED   DELIVERED   TOT_PAID   TOT_EARNED   TOT_DELIVERED
--------- ------ -------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ---------------
 1         40     30       30          60         45           40      
 1         20     15       5           60         45           40
```

Comment: You are missing a `group by` in your query.

Comment: When I add group by c.invoice_batch at end of the query, I get a `not a group by` expression message.

Comment: you should also `group by cust_id`

Comment: I'm using analytic functions here. Grouping by `invoice_batch` or `cust_id` yield an `ORA-00979: Not a group by expression` message. I don't think `group by` works well with analytic functions such as `sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove duplications from invoice_detail with *distinct* before join:

```
with invoice_detail as
(
select '10' as invoice_batch, '9999' as invoice_code from dual union all 
select '10' as invoice_batch, '9999' as invoice_code from dual union all
select '20' as invoice_batch, '1111' as invoice_code from dual union all
select '30' as invoice_batch, '9999' as invoice_code from dual
),
cust_detail as
(
select '1' as cust_id, '10' as invoice_batch, 40 as points_paid, 30 as points_earned, 30 as points_delivered from dual union all
select '1' as cust_id, '20' as invoice_batch, 10 as points_paid, 10 as points_earned, 10 as points_delivered from dual union all
select '1' as cust_id, '30' as invoice_batch, 20 as points_paid, 15 as points_earned,  5  as points_delivered from dual
)
select cust_id
            ,points_paid
            ,points_earned
            ,points_delivered
            ,sum(points_paid) over (partition by c.cust_id) as tot_paid
            ,sum(points_earned) over (partition by c.cust_id) as tot_earned
            ,sum(points_delivered) over (partition by c.cust_id) as tot_delivered           
from cust_detail c 
join (select distinct * from invoice_detail) i
     on c.invoice_batch=i.invoice_batch
where i.invoice_code = '9999';
```

Note that summaries include batches **10** and **30** because batch 20 with invoice_code='1111'.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/4834)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your desired results have to do with your query.  But, I would expect your query to look more like this:

```
select cust_id, 
       sum(points_paid) over (partition by cust_id) as batch_total
from cust_detail c inner join
     invoice_detail i
     on c.invoice_batch=i.invoice_batch
where i.invoice_code = '9999' ;
```